# bootstrap columns overlapping each other on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following code

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-3 calendar">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-9">
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's my css

.calendar {
min-width: 447px;
}

The calendar div has a minimum width of 400px; however, on smaller screens the second column overlaps with the calendar column. How do I make sure they don't overlap when the screen size is < 1024px.

Comment: Remove the minimum width or use a larger column.

Comment: @Sean Still doesn't work

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: do you use any margins on the two child divs of the container ?

Comment: Columns below into rows, you just stuck them directly into a container.

Comment: Ok I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the columns with a div giving a class name (.row) row. Make another div with calendar class in .clo-md-3 div. And use width with %

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="calendar">Calendar</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <button>Button text</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code Example:

```
.calendar { 
    min-width: 30%; 
    background: #000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it simply like this.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 bg-dark text-white">col-9</div>
  <div class="col-9 bg-info">col-3</div>
</div>
```